# Does 3d position tracking require a linear or a non-linear Kalman filter?

Tags: kalman-filter

I want to design a Kalman filter with the following details.

```
state matrix =  [Px, Py, Pz, Vx, Vy, Vz] (3d position, 3d velocity)
input control vector = [Ax, Ay, Az] (3d acceleration)
measurement matrix = [Px, Py, Pz] (3d position)
```

For me it seems to be a non-linear problem due to the presence of `acc(t * t)` factor. However I came across some videos dealing with such problems in a 2D scenario with a Linear Kalman filter.

Could you please help me in clarifying whether my scenario is an EKF problem or a simple KF problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `0.5*t*t` that occurs due to integrating the acceleration is in the transition matrix `F`.  The requirement is to be linear in terms of your state, and `t` is not part of your state.  So your system as described is linear.